# Nexus ensighten Tag Manager breaks my javascript

Tags: javascript, conflict

We are using the nexus ensighten Tag Manager for our website, it is a very important tool for our customer, so I am not allowed to remove this script from the page.

But this script seems to cause very strange behavior on my website. Many click events doesn't trigger, elements are not shown up and in every browser is another problem. So I don't know how to solve it except to remove this script from my site.

I've already tried to reorder the scripts on my page, but for some parts it works, and for other not.

Does anyone have similar problems with this Plugin and is there any solution for it?

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Tim Pope asked, *"can you contact me on Tim.pope at Ensighten dot com so we can help you"*. (His answer is probably going to be deleted soon; he does not have enough reputation to comment).

Comment: I've sent a contact request.

Comment: didn't receivy any response to my contact request :(